# Find same text and add class to elemnt with typescript ngx

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I write the following code using typescript

```
 $(function(){
      var text = $('.column-name').text();
        $('.channel-name-button').each(function(){
           if($(this).text()==text)
               $(this).addClass('select-channel-field-test');
        });
    });
```

I want to compare text from two elements and add a class

Comment: You can create a directive. Pass the value of the other element and compare it with the value where the directive is on.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cxsfza)

You can use `ElementRef`, `Renderer2`

in `AfterViewInit`

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
        var text=  this.elem.nativeElement.querySelector('.column-name').innerHTML;
        let elements = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.channel-name-button');
        elements.forEach(x=>{
          if(x.innerHTML==text){
           
            x.classList.add("select-channel-field-test");
          }
        })
  }
```